# Bitmap setPixels will lose alpha channel when background is black

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, alpha

I am trying to draw a custom view in Android, with `canvas.drawBitmap()` method. However, I found the alpha channel will be lost if I do this in native JNI code and the background is black. To summary, the case is:

1. Call java `bitmap.setPixels()` and set bitmap pixels color in NDK when background is **white**, both bitmap display correctly
2. Call java `bitmap.setPixels()` and set bitmap pixels color in NDK when background is **black**, only the bitmap drawn by java API displays correctly, the one drawn with NDK lost alpha channel

The question is why the result on white background is OK but not OK on black background? Am I missing anything or doing it in a wrong way?

**Layout XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <com.example.android.TestView
            android:id="@+id/testview1"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="320px"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

        <com.example.android.TestView
            android:id="@+id/testview2"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="320px"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <com.example.android.TestView
            android:id="@+id/testview3"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="320px"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

        <com.example.android.TestView
            android:id="@+id/testview4"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="320px"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.android;
import com.example.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TestView tv2 = (TestView) findViewById(R.id.testview2);
        TestView tv4 = (TestView) findViewById(R.id.testview4);
        tv2.setDrawFromNative();
        tv4.setDrawFromNative();
    }
}
```

**TestView.java :**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TestView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private boolean mDrawFromNative;
    private static final int WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 320;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("bitmaptest");
    }
    private native void nativeDrawBitmap(Object bitmap);

    private static void javaDrawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int pixels[] = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0x88FF0000;
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, WIDTH, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    public void setDrawFromNative() {
        mDrawFromNative = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(mDrawFromNative) {
            nativeDrawBitmap(mBitmap);
        } else {
            javaDrawBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

**TestNative.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include <android/Log.h>

#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG_TAG "BMPTEST"

extern "C" {
void Java_com_example_android_TestView_nativeDrawBitmap(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject bitmap) {

    AndroidBitmapInfo info;
    void* dst_pixels;
    int   ret;

    if((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &dst_pixels)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }

    unsigned int *dst = (unsigned int *)dst_pixels;
    for(int i=0; i< info.width * info.height; i++) {
            *(dst+i) = (0x88<<24 | 0xff | 0x00<<8 | 0x00<<16); //(ARGB->ABGR)
    }
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
}
```

**Android.mk for native code:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libbitmaptest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    TestNative.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**ScreenShot of the result:**
[image: ScreenShot of the result]

Comment: How about if you switch the byte order in your native code? (i.e. `0x0000ff11`)

Comment: The byte order is correct in my code (red with alpha 0x11) on ARM platform. Use 0x0000ff11 will cause the bitmap to be a opaque green rectangle.

Comment: I have updated the question with detailed source code and screen shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android stores bitmaps with pre-multiplied alpha. When you call `setPixels()` from Java, the RGB color values are automatically multiplied by the alpha values and stored in the bitmap. However, when you call `Android_lockPixels()` from native code and then write directly to the memory, you need to do the pre-multiplication yourself or else it's going to turn out wrong. If you change your code to:

```
 int premultipliedR = (0xff * 0x88) >> 8;
 for(int i=0; i< info.width * info.height; i++) {
        *(dst+i) = (0x88<<24 | premultipliedR | 0x00<<8 | 0x00<<16);
```

then both `Bitmap`s should render the same.

So why does it *appear* as if the bitmaps lose the alpha channel when the background is black but not for a white background? Well it turns out that's just a coincidence based on the numbers you've chosen.

The basic alpha blending formula is:

```
 dest.r = ((dest.r * (256 - source.a)) + (source.r * source.a)) >> 8;
 dest.g = ((dest.g * (256 - source.a)) + (source.g * source.a)) >> 8;
 dest.b = ((dest.b * (256 - source.a)) + (source.b * source.a)) >> 8;
```

where `dest` is the background pixel and source is the pixel in your bitmap. Pre-multiplying the alpha changes this to:

```
 dest.r = ((dest.r * (256 - source.a)) >> 8) + source.premultiplied_r;
 dest.g = ((dest.g * (256 - source.a)) >> 8) + source.premultiplied_g;
 dest.b = ((dest.b * (256 - source.a)) >> 8) + source.premultiplied_b;
```

which saves a bunch of multiplies. The results are all clamped to 255. I'm not claiming this is the exact formula used, but it is something pretty close to it.

Plugging the numbers in, for your Java bitmap, pre-multiplied r, g, b are going to be 0x87 (or 0x88 depending on how they do the rounding etc), 0x00 and 0x00. For your native bitmap, they are going to be 0xff, 0x00 and 0x00 because you didn't pre-multiply. Alpha-blending this with a black background is the same as just adding zero, since the `dest.` `r`, `g`, `b` values are all zero. So *the results look different*.

In the case of a white background, `dest.g` and `dest.b` are going to end up the same in both cases, since the pre-multiplied `g` and `b` values are zero in both the Java and native bitmaps. In the case of `dest.r`, the result should be 255. In the case of the native bitmap, the value overflows because of the wrong value for pre-multiplied `r`, but it gets clamped to 255, so *the results end up looking the same*.

In short, the pre-multipled `r` value is too high for your native bitmap, so you end up with a too-high `r` value in cases where the result should have been < 255. In cases where the result should have been 255, it doesn't matter if it's too high because it gets clamped at 255 anyway.

Comment: When you say premultipliedR, you mean premultipliedAlpha, right? I changed my code as you suggested, the result is the same. I still get a opaque red rectangle on black background different from the semi-transparent one drawn by Java api. Or did I misunderstand your answer, should I change the *(dst+i)=??? If you could use my code and modify it to get a correct result that would be fantastic.

Comment: One more question on this topic, if all the R/G/B is stored as premultiplied, is it still necessary to keep the alpha in the pixel? I mean, does *(dst+i) = (WHATEVER_VALUE<<24) | premultipliedR | 0x00<<8 | 0x00<<16); will get the same result?

Comment: Yes, you still need it because the dest RGB is being multiplied by 256 minus the alpha value in the blend equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving me on this problem, I was stuck here for 2 days. A last question: is there any "official" APIs that can tell the framework that the current pixel buffer content is NOT premultiplied, thus it need to be multiplied and maybe framework can use some hardware acceleration faster than my for{} loop? I tried bitmap.setPremultiplied(false) will give a crash...

Comment: setPremultiplied is the only one I'm aware of. The crash might be a RunTimeException caused by calling createBitmap (see the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPremultiplied(boolean) ). perhaps try calling it after you call createBitmap? Other than that I don't know.